# If first $_GET field is empty but second has a value, echo to fill in missing value

Tags: php, forms

I want it to say "Please fill in the form below:" at first, before any input, but afterwards if they input an age but no name, I want it to say:
"Please enter a name:"
and if they input a name but no age then:
"Please enter your age:"
but if they submit nothing then:
"ERROR: Please enter your name AND age to continue"

Here is the code I have:

```
   if( $_GET["name"] && $_GET["age"] ) {
  echo "<p>Welcome ". $_GET['name']. " ... ";
  echo "You are ". $_GET['age']. " years old.</p>";

  exit();
   } elseif ( $_GET["name"] == FALSE ) {
       echo "<p>Please fill in the form below:</p>";
   } elseif ( $_GET["age"] == FALSE ) {
       echo "<p>Please fill in the form below:</p>";
   } elseif ( $_GET["name"] == FALSE && $_GET["age"] ) {
       echo "<p>Please fill in your name:</p>";
   } elseif ( $_GET["age"] == FALSE && $_GET["name"] ) {
       echo "<p>Please fill in your age:</p>";
   }
```

I'm just learning PHP and I've tried everything I can think of, this is what I've ended up with so far!

Thank you.

Comment: submitting a form really should be using the `$_POST` method

Comment: This could be done in one line using an `||` (OR) statement.

Comment: Consider using client-side form validation.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation  It's standardized now, and there are good polyfills for browsers that don't yet support it.  You still have to validate data integrity server-side (as it's impossible to prevent people from hijacking your form post to send in whatever they want) but then you can simply throw an error if the data is unexpected, rather than dealing with all the work needed to make a friendly form.

Comment: you can do it in html no hassle

Comment: Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `FALSE` with  [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and you're almost there

Your form:

```
<form method='post' ... >
 <input type='text' name='name' value=''>
...
</form>
```

Then your PHP:

```
  if( $_POST["name"] ... ) {
  ...
  exit;
} 
elseif ( empty($_POST["name"]) ) {
       echo "<p>Please fill in the form below:</p>";
   } elseif ( empty($_POST['age'] || !is_numeric($_POST["age"]) ) {
       echo "<p>Please fill in the form below:</p>";
   } elseif ( empty($_POST['name'] && !empty($_POST['age'] ) {
       echo "<p>Please fill in your name:</p>";
   } elseif (  !empty($_POST['name'] && empty($_POST['age']) {
       echo "<p>Please fill in your age:</p>";
   }
```

You should really restructure your logic so that your two values are independent

- Check if name is filled in.
- Check if age is filled in.
- return echo statement to user.

So the above series of `elseif` statements can become...

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])){
    $notice .= " Please enter your name.";
}
if(empty($_POST['age'])){
    $notice .= " Please Enter your age." 
}
print $notice.
```

The `.=` concatenates the new definition on to the end of the current (or empty) value of the variable. You can print the `$notice` every time because it is either empty (nothing printed) or it has a value, which is something you want to print, so it's win win every time.

Comment: this can be further condensed but left like this to illustrate the idea...